# How to turn a List of Eithers to a Either of Lists using scalaz.MonadPlus.separate

Tags: scala, scalaz

How to turn a `List` of `Eithers` to a `Either` of `Lists`, using `MonadPlus.separate`?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30960721/280393) the author claims this solution, but fails to provide the imports or complete example:

> If scalaz is one of your dependencies I would simply use separate:
>
> ```
> val el : List[Either[Int, String]] = List(Left(1), Right("Success"), Left(42))
>
> scala> val (lefts, rights) = el.separate
> lefts: List[Int] = List(1, 42)
> rights: List[String] = List(Success)
> ```

Is this a real working solution?
I see that [`MonadPlus`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.2/scalaz_2.11-7.2.2-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.MonadPlus) has a `separate` function but I still didn't manage to make it work.

ps: I am aware I can achieve this without scalaz, such as the example below. However, in this question I am asking how to use `scalaz.MonadPlus.separate` to achieve this.

```
(lefts, rights) = (el.collect { case Left(left) => left }, el.collect { case Right(right) => right })
```

Comment: When in doubt, import it all.. `import scalaz._, Scalaz._`

Comment: If you want the specific imports you can look at [my similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36556060/5020846) to what seems to be a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: anyone knows how to do this in cats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution is correct, you're just missing `import scalaz.Scalaz._` here.