# Flatten List[Either[A, B]] to List[B] like List[Option[B]] to List[B]

Tags: scala, flatten, scala-cats, either

Does Cats provide flattening akin to

```
implicit class FlattenListOfEither[L, R](l: List[Either[L, R]]) {
  def flattenM: List[R] = l collect { case Right(v) => v }
}
```

such that

```
val l1: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left("error"), Right(4))
l1.flattenM
```

outputs

```
List(1, 2, 4)
```

similar to how vanilla Scala flattens list of options

```
val l2: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(4))
l2.flatten
```

which outputs

```
List(1, 2, 4)
```

[`separate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30960721/5205022) gives the following syntax

```
import cats.implicits._
val (_, rights) = l1.separate
rights
```

which outputs

```
List(1, 2, 4)
```

however does there exist out-of-the-box `flatten`-like extension method which returns just the rights instead of the tuple?

Comment: I doubt such method exists. It make no sense on general abstractions like **Monads**, as you would need a way to see any nested element as of the same type of the outer. The case with option works, because on the _stdlib_ an **Option** can be _implicitly_ converted into an **IterabeOnce** _(of just one element)_ - being honest I do not like that, but that is another discussion. Now, if it would be an especial method only for inner **Eithers** then `separate` is the one that makes more sense - IMHO, the best would be yo create your own extension method, using `collect`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest is to use `mapFilter` provided by the `FunctorFilter` typeclass.
It looks like this:

```
def mapFilter[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): F[B]
```

Where `F[A]` could be `List[A]`, or `Vector[A]` or any other type that allows filtering.

If we apply this function to your list, we just need to turn the `Either[A, B]`s into `Option[B]`s. This is as easy as calling `toOption`.
With that the full solution looks like this:

```
import cats.implicits._

val l1: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left("error"), Right(4))

l1.mapFilter(_.toOption)
// List(1, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to remark that

```
listOfEithers.flatMap(_.toOption)
```

with plain vanilla Scala-collection methods seems to do what you want:

```
val x = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left("error"), Right(4))
x.flatMap(_.toOption) // res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)
```

Comment: If using vanilla, personally I find `collect { case Right(v) => v }` clearer, but I feel `flatten` communicates the concept perfectly (if it existed)

Comment: @MarioGalic I don't know. I find LukaJacobowitz's `mapFilter` slightly shorter and nicer than `collect`, but then I find that `flatMap` looks almost like `mapFilter`, but does not require that I look it up in the documentation, but then again I see that `collect` expresses the intent cleaner than `flatMap`. It's circular, like rock-paper-scissors, not sure which one I like more :D

Answer (score 1):

What about `partitionMap` in `Scala 2.13`? (note sure what you mean by `shorter`):

```scala
   val l1: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left("error"), Right(4))
    val (_, rights) = l1.partitionMap(identity)
    println(rights)
 // Displays
 // List(1, 2, 4)
```

Comment: By shorter,  I mean it returns just the rights instead of the tuple.